# Uninstall .NET framework 4.7 and install 4.5 in Azure machine

Tags: .net, azure, .net-framework-version

[image]

I wanted to uninstall .NET 4.7 and install 4.5 as I am using an old application which depends on the 4.5 version.
Now I use a Powershell script to redeploy the application jobs in a new Azure server, but the Azure machine has .NET framework 4.7.1 installed and it is not allowing me to uninstall kb:4054590 which will take the server back to 4.5.

I've tried many steps but it is still not resolved. The server says kb:4054590 is mandated for this machine. In this situation either I have to skip the validation or dependency of that application or downgrade the server to .NET 4.5.

[image]

Comment: Is the application demanding 4.5 when you try to install it, or are you assuming this based on documentation? Because the .NET runtime as installed (even as 4.7.1) should, I believe, support applications that run under 4.5.

Comment: Have you actually tried to run that application on .NET (4.7)? .NET 4.x versions should be [(backwards) compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility), and usually there are no issues.

Comment: @Nanhydrin Yes the application is demanding for 4.5, can i change the dependency to 4.7 ? how to do that

Comment: @Christian.K Oh okay sure thanks , but still am getting error, i guess the script might be checking for specific DWORD number of tat .net version

Comment: please check the link "enter image description here" for actual error

Comment: It's hard to know what your task (looks like powershell) is doing. Maybe it's expecting to find resources that "define" if .net 4.x is installed and isn't finding them, because the 4.x installed is > 4.5. Can you remove the strictly required validation your task has, or expand it to pass for and 4.x version of .net runtime?